# Proper database practices

Tags: mysql, database

I'm a bit newer to structuring databases and I was wondering if, say I have 38 different pieces of data that I want to have per record. Is it better to break that up into say a couple different tables or can I just keep it all in one table.

In this case I have a table of energy usage data for accounts, I have monthly usage, monthly demand, and demand percentage, then 2 identifying keys for each which comes out to 38 pieces of data for each record.

So is it good practice to break it up or should I just leave that all as one table? Also are there any effects on the efficiency of the product doing queries once this database ends up accumulating a couple thousand records at it peak?

Edit: I'm using Hibernate to query, I'm not sure if that would have any effect on the efficiency depending on how I end up breaking this data up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the normal forms:

1) [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)
2) [A Simple Guide to Five Normal Forms in Relational Database Theory](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm)

Second, aggregation data like "monthly sales" or "daily clicks" typically go to a separate tables. This is motivated not only by normal forms, but also by the implementation of the database.
For example, MySQL offers the *Archive* storage engine which is designed for that.

If you're watching current month's data, these may appear in the same table, or can be stored in cache. The per-month data in a separated table may be computed 1st day of month.

Comment: That makes some sense. In my situation though I'm looking at each user having one set of this data then it's changed on and inconsistent base by the end user, and I have already eliminated all dependencies among this data. So the question really is if you have a large amount of data not dependent on each other can you throw that all in one table?

Comment: @gcalex5 It seems strange to throw a grab-bag of data in a table together. What does a record in the table represent? With 38 fields, do you get duplication in the data? Maybe showing us your table description would help drive some more answers.

Comment: I usually separate generated data and user submitted data, and treat existence of both in the application - showing the preferred "if they exist". One reason for that - you can regenerate the data later, but still keep user-submitted. Whether to keep them in the same table depends on what's more practical for you. If you're not depending on slight change in performance, and the rest of schema isn't too complicated, I'd split.

Comment: A record in the table represents jan-dec energy usage, jan-dec energy demand, jan-dec on-peak usage, then obligation percentages... which is all being used by and algorithm to create dynamic pricing estimations on a different page of the application, so this data is only queried on request by the end user

Comment: Ad "Schema too complicated" - I mean, with Hibernate, dealing with too many tables/entities may end up with a bit of mess and complicated development of DAO layer. So sometimes I resort to keeping data in one table, although not glad to.

Comment: Alright thanks that was kind of my line of thinking as well

Answer (score 1):

when you read a record do you use *often* all data? or you have different sections or masks (loaded separatly) to show energy usage data, monthly statistics and so on?

how many records do you plan to have on this table? If they grow dramatically and continually, is it possible create tables with a postfix for grouping them by period (for month, half year, year ...)?

Comment: the data that is entered by a user which is the only thing saved is there estimation on usage or one years bills, so there aren't multiple records for each which I think is what you are getting at if I interpreted you correctly? And as for records it shouldn't grow beyond 2,000

Comment: in this case you can do what you want.. i suggest to take one table with user detail and another one for statistics; if this drastically grow you can implement a multiple-table (grouping them by period or other).